# Failed to validate redirect uri during authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive

I am trying to authenticate user by following these authorization [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#step-1-log-in-and-get-an-authorization-code) with redirect uri on non standard port, using following URl

https://my.domain.com:1150/api/onedrive/authenticate

and i am getting response like redirect_uri is not valid

but on other side when i try to authenticate user without the port "1150", it gets create successfully

Both registered application `callback URI` and `redirect_uri` are same.

Please help!

Comment: Make sure the value you specify for `redirect_uri` exactly matches one of the values in `Reply URLs` collection for your registered application (same one you're using clientid and other details for).. You can check Reply URLs in Azure portal > Azure AD > App Registraitons > Your app registration > Settings > Reply URLs .. here's a quick screenshot.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZb25.png

Comment: Both registered application `callback URI` and `redirect_uri ` are same

Comment: and does the redirect_uri value which is not working for you, i.e. the one with port 1150 mentioned as part of Reply URLs for app registration.. as I showed in screenshot for previous comment?

Comment: You could also try to URL encode the value you provide as part of `redirect_uri` .. It's mentioned briefly on microsoft docs.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDxMs.png on this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it and let you know.